# Error running .wav sounds on the simulator

Tags: audio, wav, codenameone

I must have something misconfigured - a missing library perhaps?
I get this error when trying to play a .wav sound in the simulator.

### I have jfxrt.jar in the build path.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMediaPlayer.gstGetAudioSpectrum(J)J
at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMediaPlayer.gstGetAudioSpectrum(Native Method)
at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMediaPlayer.<init>(GSTMediaPlayer.java:57)
at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMediaPlayer.<init>(GSTMediaPlayer.java:62)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are running on one VM while having the jfxrt.jar from another VM in the path. Try making sure that you are running on Java 8 where this should "just work". Make sure that in the "Library" section in netbeans JDK 8 is selected.

Comment: I'm using eclipse.  Audio works in your "flickr" demo, using the canned jars, but not in the live simulator environment I built there.   Something in the environment that replaces CLDC11.jar is probably not right.

Comment: Either way make sure you are using Java 8 as the runtime which should allow this.

Comment: Is it possible you are using 1.8 and the jfxrt from a different sdk?

Comment: no, it's all from the same binary.   i suppose I need to locate the javafx sources to see what's going on.